# Is it possible to know the location of the Google server running an Apps Script project?

Tags: google-apps-script

According to the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), scripts are run on Google's servers. Is it possible to know or specify the region/zone/location of the server running the script? (like, for example, we would do for Google Cloud App Engine or Compute Engine)

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but you can get and set the script's timezone - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getscripttimezone).